# Short name for Autosys MAchine

Tags: alias, autosys

Hi Can any one advice how to make aliases for AutoSys machine name
something like -1045_VM_AMDGC_APP_DEV2 i am using the whole name and unable to find how to make  aliases.

As a work around i insert a machine that points to a random dns and then update command to point to an existing agent machine to create an alias. is okay or is there a simpler way to do it.
I tried to use insert alias with node name pointing to the real machine but does not allow like that and gives machine already exists error even if the machine name is different.

```
insert_machine:ALiasname
type:a
nodename:vmsometjing..network.network
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with virtual machines:

```
insert_machine: aliasname
type: v
machine: 1045_VM_AMDGC_APP_DEV2
```

Then you just need to update the job to point to the aliasname and all will be good, make sure when you delete the machine to update the definition of the virtual as well.

Comment: Do you know in what case i should use node name then ?also  if the machine is a dns alaias do i need to look into anything else as well or just update the dns name  should do the trick?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply... When adding a real machine or DNS entry you would use a node name, as for creating the virtual machine you need already defined node first. You can have multiple machines under a VM in autosys that you can then have alternate between all nodes/machines, do round robin or based on load. But if you are doing DNS, I assume you would just use that since the server team or network team would manage the load balancing on what happens behind the DNS.